# How to only only allow ONE item to be selected at a time

Tags: html, typescript, angular5

Angular 5 - on (click) when one node is active, all other nodes need to be inactive. The node selected will turn Green ('active' in CSS - [ngClass]) and all others that aren't the current node selected should turn black.

here is my HTML and typescript
HTML:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-8" (contextmenu)="onRightClick($event, node)">
      <div class="toggle" [ngClass]="{'active': node.isActive}" (click)="activeButton(node)">
        <div [ngStyle]="node.styles()">
            <i *ngIf="node.getChildren().length > 0 && !node.isExpanded()"
               (click)="node.toggle()">
              <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            </i>
            <i *ngIf="node.getChildren().length > 0 && node.isExpanded()"
               (click)="node.toggle()">
              <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
            </i>
            <i *ngIf="node.getChildren().length === 0">
              <i class="fa fa-circle-notch"></i>
            </i>
              {{node.title}}
```

typescript:

```
activeButton(node) {
if (node.isActive) {
  const index = this.data.indexOf(node);
  console.log(this.data.indexOf(node));
  if (this.data.indexOf(node) !== -1) {
    this.data[index] = node;
    console.log(this.data.indexOf(node));
    node.isActive = false;
  }
}
node.isActive = true;
```

}

Comment: You only go into the isActive=false part, if you click on an active node. Looks like a toggle function. Easiest thing you be to set all nodes to isActive = false (without a condition). And at the end let the part with node.isActive = true;

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it is currently a toggle function. Currently all nodes are set to isActive=false until they are clicked, which will activate the isActive toggle. When one node is clicked I want all others to be inactive.. Still unsure how to achieve this.. sorry, fairly new to programming.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise to go the route @Edub had advised in the comments, so that'd be:

```
activeButton(currentNode): void {
  this.data = this.data.map(node => {
    node.isActive = false;
    return node;
  });

  // or this.data.forEach(node => node.isActive = false);

  if (currentNode.isActive) {
    const index = this.data.indexOf(currentNode);

    if (this.data.indexOf(currentNode) !== -1) {
      currentNode.isActive = false;
      this.data[index] = currentNode;
    }
  }

  currentNode.isActive = true;
}
```

Comment: thanks alex! My html is the same and I have replaced my function with what you suggested. I am getting error "shadowed name 'node' no shadowed variable" under the node here ---> this.data.map(node =>

Comment: Ah yes, that's because the method parameter and the arrow function's one is the same, I'll amend the code for you.